KivyのRecycleViewでBoxLayoutを使い入れ子構造にした時に異常が発生する
環境:
Python: 3.11.5
Kivy: 2.3.0
RecycleViewを使い、viewlassをBoxLayoutにして、その中身が動的に変化する場合を考えます。今回は中身をLabelにし、その数は読み込み時にランダムに決定されるとします。
試したコードはこちらで、問題なく動きました。
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from random import randint

KV = '''
<RVLabel>:
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, .2, .3, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RVBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 10
    height: self.minimum_height

RecycleView:
    viewclass: 'RVBoxLayout'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size: None, None
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
'''

class RVBoxLayout(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.clear_widgets()
        for d in data['box']:
            self.add_widget(
                RVLabel(
                    text=f'{d} --------------- The label must wrap when it is long.'
                )
            )
        return super(RVBoxLayout, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

class RVLabel(Label):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        rv = self.root.__self__

        for i in range(6):
            box_layout_data = {'box':
                [f'Label {j}' for j in range(randint(1, 5))]
            }
            rv.data.append(box_layout_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()

しかし、テキストが折り返されたときに、ラベルの高さが自動調節されるようにLabelを
<RVLabel>:
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]

としたところ、
<ClockEvent (-1.0) callback=<bound method Label.texture_update of <__main__.RVLabel object at 0x000001EA63523CB0>>>

というようなログが無限に表示されてしまい、ウィンドウもラベルがランダムに出たり消えたりします。どうすれば正しく表示されるでしょうか？

ウィンドウサイズを変更すると, テキストの折り返しが発生することがあり, このときはラベルの高さは自動で変わるようです。この質問の「しかし、テキストが折り返されたときに」とはどういった場合でしょうか？ 質問の元のコードでは対処できてないですか？

ご指摘ありがとうございます。元のコードだとウィンドウサイズを変更したときにテキストは折り返されますが、ラベルの高さは変わりません。RVLabelのsize_hint_y: Noneのせいです。

エラーメッセージに
<ClockEvent (-1.0) callback=<bound method Label.texture_update of <__main__.RVLabel object at 0x000001EA63523CB0>>>
<ClockEvent (-1.0) callback=<bound method BoxLayout.do_layout of <__main__.RVBoxLayout object at 0x7f0539a998d0>>>
<ClockEvent (-1.0) callback=<bound method RecycleViewBehavior.refresh_views of <kivy.uix.recycleview.__init__.RecycleView object at 0x7fd98b179160>>>

が大量にあることから、ウィジットのレイアウトの計算に循環依存が発生して計算が終わらなくなっているように見えます。何故それが起きるのかはまだ分かってないですが色々いじっている内にそれを起こさない方法にたどり着いたので紹介しますね。
手順1 RVLabelを再利用する
RVBoxLayout.refresh_view_attrs()内ではRVLabelを生成しています。つまりせっかくRVBoxLayout自体がRecycle(再利用) されているのに内部では別のウィジットを使い捨てしている事になり効率面では本末転倒な状態です。なのでまずはここを直しました。
class RVBoxLayout(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    @cached_property
    def _cached_labels(self):
        return []

    def get_labels(self, n):
        labels = self._cached_labels
        if len(labels) < n:
            labels.extend(RVLabel() for _ in range(n - len(labels)))
        return labels

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.clear_widgets()
        for d, label in zip(data['box'], self.get_labels(len(data['box']))):
            label.text = f'{d} --------------- The label must wrap when it is long.'
            self.add_widget(label)
        return super(RVBoxLayout, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

手順2 default_size を None, None にしない
もし私の書いた記事を参考にそうしたのなら申し訳ないですがどうやら今回default_size: None, None が悪さをしているようです。手順1に加えて
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        # default_size: None, None  # <-- コメントアウト

とする事でエラーは出なくなりました。
別解？
質問者さんが投稿したコードは実際のアプリのコードより簡略化された物だと思うのでこれは解法にはならないかもしれないですが、可能ならRVBoxLayoutを用いずにRVLabelを直接viewclassにして改行入りの文字列を与える方が必要なウィジットの総数が減ってより良いです。

おっしゃる通りで、今回のミソは入れ子構造にすることなので回答1をいただくこととします。
回答1は概ね良好に動きましたが、僕の環境ですとなぜかdefault_size: None, Noneがある方が正常に動きます。コメントアウトすると一部のラベルが描画されず、その部分は空白になります。そして、スクロールさせたり、ウィンドウサイズを変えて文字列を折り返させると消えていたラベルは描画されます。


僕の環境ですとdefault_size: None, Noneがあった方が良好に動きます。何がそうさせていると思われますか？  ----  分からないですね。後はソースコードを読んで解明するしか無いと思います。

